# How to compress a dataframe so that the row-to-row difference is at least some threshold in magnitude

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame containing approximately 7000 rows and 2 columns which looks like this:

```py
    Time    Voltage
0    0.0  32.965541
1    0.5  32.914965
2    1.0  32.904850
3    1.5  32.864389
4   14.0  31.680907
5   24.0  31.023417
6   24.5  31.003186
7   25.0  30.982956
8   25.5  30.942495
9   26.0  30.952610
10  50.0  30.062469
11  50.5  30.022009
12  56.0  29.961317
13  56.5  29.941087
14  57.0  29.930971
15  57.5  29.910741
16  58.0  29.890511
17  73.0  21.211641
18  73.5  21.181296
19  74.0  21.201526
20  87.5  21.120604
21  88.0  21.080143
22  88.5  21.110489
```

I want to "compress" the dataframe to only time steps that correspond with a voltage difference of magnitude of at least one volt from one step to the next.

For example, starting at time `0.0`, the next voltage whose difference in magnitude is at least one volt is at time `14.0`. Then, from time `14.0`, the next voltage whose difference in magnitude is at least one volt is at time `50.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### New answer

Okay so after some time, I think I've finally come to understand what you're asking. It seems that you want to essentially "compress" the data so that *each chronological time step has a difference in voltage that is at least 1V in magnitude*.

For example, starting with the voltage at time `0.0`, the next voltage whose difference is at least of magnitude 1V is the voltage at time `14.0`. Then, starting from the voltage at time `14.0`, the next voltage difference above the magnitude threshold is at time `50.0`. Then you start looking from time `50.0`, and so on.

This can be achieved using what's known as a two-pointer algorithm. You essentially track -- no surprise -- two pointers: one which is fixed at a certain index, and one that increments one step at a time from the first pointer. Then when some condition is met, the first pointer is updated to the second pointer's location, and the second pointer then starts incrementing again. Here's a basic implementation:

```py
def compress(x, thresh=1):
    i, j, idxs = 0, 1, [0]
    while j < len(x):
        if abs(x[i] - x[j]) >= thresh:
            idxs.append(j)
            i = j
        j += 1
    return idxs
```

Which, when passed the `Voltage` column from the dataframe produces this result:

```py
In [26]: df.iloc[compress(df.Voltage, 1), :]
Out[26]:
    Time    Voltage
0    0.0  32.965541
4   14.0  31.680907
10  50.0  30.062469
17  73.0  21.211641
```

### Old answer

I'll leave this old answer up so that future readers may still benefit from it.

You can get the change from one row above with `.diff()`:

```py
In [7]: df["deltaVoltage"] = df["Voltage"].diff()

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
    Time    Voltage  deltaVoltage
0    0.0  32.965541           NaN
1    0.5  32.914965     -0.050576
2    1.0  32.904850     -0.010115
3    1.5  32.864389     -0.040461
4   14.0  31.680907     -1.183482
5   24.0  31.023417     -0.657490
6   24.5  31.003186     -0.020230
7   25.0  30.982956     -0.020230
8   25.5  30.942495     -0.040461
9   26.0  30.952610      0.010115
10  50.0  30.062469     -0.890140
11  50.5  30.022009     -0.040461
12  56.0  29.961317     -0.060691
13  56.5  29.941087     -0.020230
14  57.0  29.930971     -0.010115
15  57.5  29.910741     -0.020230
16  58.0  29.890511     -0.020230
17  73.0  21.211641     -8.678869
18  73.5  21.181296     -0.030346
19  74.0  21.201526      0.020230
20  87.5  21.120604     -0.080922
21  88.0  21.080143     -0.040461
22  88.5  21.110489      0.030346
```

Then, you can select the rows where the absolute value in the change in voltage is `>= 1`:

```py
In [9]: df[df["deltaVoltage"].abs() >= 1]
Out[9]:
    Time    Voltage  deltaVoltage
4   14.0  31.680907     -1.183482
17  73.0  21.211641     -8.678869
```

Or, if you don't actually want the change in voltage saved as a column:

```py
In [10]: df[df["Voltage"].diff().abs() >= 1]
Out[10]:
    Time    Voltage
4   14.0  31.680907
17  73.0  21.211641
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my problem description and I just realized it now after I used your solution. What I wanted is all the voltage values with time columns if the voltage changes at least by 1, the difference of 1 doesn't exactly has to be exactly from the last value . For example for the above given data I want to select index 0 then maybe 6,11,16..... and so on. I might adjust the difference (maybe 1 or 0.9 or 0.8  ) later on. 
I also need to mention here the voltage values are not always in descending order.

Comment: It's not clear what you're saying. What I provided *does* give you all the voltage changes that are at least `1` in magnitude (either `<= -1` or `>= 1`) ***from one time step to the next***. It's also not clear what you mean when you say you want to select "maybe" some other indices. That's a different problem...

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. For example, first voltage values is 32.965541, if the next value is 31.965541 or less, or 33.965541 or more than I want to keep that value and corresponding time value. All the values in between will be discarded. So that it would look something like this.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EkCCegZFn-fJMyLrQ7Y9aXz1CzWmztBi/view?usp=sharing

I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clicking on that link. You seem to be ***still*** describing exactly what I've delivered

Comment: OK, just look at the voltage value of index 0, 4 and 10 the difference between 0 and 4 is 1.284634, which is more than 1, so I want to keep voltage value of index 4 which is 31.680907. Again look at the value of index 10, 30.062469. Difference of 4 and 10 is 1.618438.  So I want to keep voltage value of index 10.  I am keeping index 0 then 4 and then 10...
Now look at your solution which finds the difference of index 9 and 10 and the difference is 0.890141, which is less than 1, hence index 10 will be discarded, which I don't want.
The solution you provided it solves my problem partially.

Comment: So you want to calculate the voltage difference between ***any arbitrary pair of times?*** If not, what is the logic behind determining which pairs of time-voltage measurements you want to compare? ***Do you understand that there are ~24.5 million different pairs of time-voltage measurements out of a dataframe with 7000 rows?*** That's just pairs of measurements from one timestep to a later timestep, and does not include the reverse pairings, which would double the number of voltage differences to ~48 million...

Comment: Okay, @Nazmul1001 I think I understand what you're asking now. Please see my edit.